# In this example, why isn't the variable properly typed in early binding?

Tags: c++

I ran across this example while studying early binding vs late binding, and I'm realizing that I really have no idea how compiling really works.

Here, the output is `"Instrument::play"`, even though it really should be `"Wind::play"`, but this can be changed by making the function `Instrument::play` a virtual function.

I can clearly see that the object `flute` is a `Wind` object, not an `Instrument` object. Would I be wrong in assuming that the compiler would know this as well? I mean, I figure compilers would always type-check function parameters, so in this case, wouldn't it check to see if an appropriate `Instrument` object was used, see that it's a `Wind` object, and automatically select the `Wind` version of `play()`?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
enum note { middleC, Csharp, Eflat }; // Etc.

class Instrument {
public:
  void play(note) const {
    cout << "Instrument::play" << endl;
  }
};

class Wind : public Instrument {
public:
  
  void play(note) const {
    cout << "Wind::play" << endl;
  }
};

void tune(Instrument i) {
  i.play(middleC);
}


int main()
{
  int a = 1+1;
  Wind flute;
  tune(flute);
}
```

Comment: polymorphic beahvior only works through pointers and references.

Comment: Bottom line -- C++ is not Python or Java.

Comment: @Mezzoforte "*Would I be wrong in assuming that the compiler would know this as well?*" - Yes. "*wouldn't [the compiler] check to see if an appropriate Instrument object was used, see that it's a Wind object, and automatically select the Wind version of play()?*" - No. Polymorphic dispatch via `virtual` methods will handle that at runtime. However, you are **slicing** the `flute` object when passing it to `tune()` as an `Instrument` *by value*, so it wouldn't matter if `Instrument::play()` were `virtual` (which it should be). You need to pass it by reference/pointer instead to avoid slicing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So when the compiler checks that flute is a wind object, what exactly happens? I know about upcasting. Is that what happens? It gets upcasted into a instrument object, and thus instrument::play gets invoked?

Comment: C++ follows an ideology of only making a program pay for what it asks for, and runtime polymorphism has a (typically small) cost, so you have to ask for it with the `virtual` keyword if you really do want use it and are OK paying the performance penalty.

Comment: In this case there is no casting involved. You're passing the object by value, so a copy of the object is made. The receiving function only accepts an `Instrument`, so all of the `Wind`ness of the source object is lost, sliced away, so that the copy can be an `Instrument`.

Comment: @Mezzoforte Even if slicing weren't an issue, ie if `flute` were passed into `tune()` by reference/pointer instead, the code would still only call `Instrument::play()` instead of `Wind::play()` unless `Instrument::play()` were `virtual` and `Wind` overrode it. Which the original code is not doing. `i.play()` is a static method call at compile-time, and the type of `i` is `Instrument` at compile-time. To have `i.play()` call `Wind::play()` at runtime requires `i.play()` to be dispatched via polymorphism, and that requires `Instrument::play()` to be `virtual` and overridden by `Wind::play()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You say that the type of i is Instrument at compile time, and that's just the part that confuses me the most. When the compiler needs to check what argument was passed to it, you say it sees flute as an Instrument object. Is this because of upcasting? (I'm talking about the case where tune accepts a pointer/reference, not the original code that I wrote).

Comment: @Mezzoforte the compiler does that validation at the site where `tune()` is being called, not inside of `tune()` itself. An `Instrument&` reference, or an `Instrument*` pointer, will refer-to/point-at the `Instrument` *portion* of the object that is being passed in. Inside of `tune()`, it just knows about `Instrument` only, nothing more (unless you *explicity* type-cast the reference/pointer to another type, ie via `dynamic_cast` or `static_cast`).

Comment: Potentially helpful reading: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Okay, I totally get it now. Thanks!

Comment: @Mezzoforte -- Are you basing your conclusions on what happens with languages like Python or Java (or similar)?  If so, then this is why you can't use those languages as models in understanding or writing C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

polymorphic behavior only works through pointers and references.

Do this

```
void tune(Instrument *i) {
  i->play(middleC);
}


int main()
{
  int a = 1+1;
  Wind flute;
  tune(&flute);
}
```

plus the methods need to be virtual

```
class Instrument {
public:
  virtual void play(note) const {
    cout << "Instrument::play" << endl;
  }
};

class Wind : public Instrument {
public:
  
  virtual void play(note) const {
    cout << "Wind::play" << endl;
  }
};
```

Comment: I tried just the first part, and I'm still getting an output of Instrument::play. Is that what I'm supposed to expect?

Comment: @pm100 A reference would make more sense than a pointer in this example: `void tune(Instrument &i) { i.play(middleC); } ... Wind flute; tune(flute);`

Comment: @Mezzoforte `play()` must be `virtual` in `Instrument` to get the behavior you want. `Wind` can then `override` it

Comment: @RemyLebeau I get that, but I'm wondering why is it that when the compiler is typechecking flute and sees that it is a wind object, that i.play(middleC) doesn't get redefined into the wind version as well. I mean, the COMPILER CLEARLY sees that flute is a wind object not an instrument object, right? By the way, I see my mistake in using the value instead of a reference, and am not asking about that issue anymore.

Comment: @Mezzoforte public inheritance means that any `Wind` "is a" `Instrument`, just that to make use of it you need to use pointers or references

Comment: @Mezzoforte "*why is it that when the compiler is typechecking `flute` and sees that it is a `Wind` object, **that `i.play(middleC)` doesn't get redefined into the wind version***" - the compiler doesn't do that (and CANT do that, well not the way you have coded it). It knows that `tune()` takes an `Instrument`, and that `Wind` derives from `Instrument`, so you can pass `flute` into `tune()`, however inside of `tune()`, it doesn't know that it was passed a `Wind` object, in fact it could be passed *any* type of object that derives from `Instrument`, not just `Wind`.